# Change on every other row

Tags: php, row

I have problem with that the first row misses a `<tr>` and then there is one line and then there is a `</tr>` and then it works perfect with one `<tr>` and two lines and `</tr>` and so on. How to change the code to make that work?

Any ideas to use "div" instead of "table"?

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<?
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY id ASC");
            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 

            { 
                if(++$s % 2 == 0) { echo '<tr>'."\r\n"; }
                echo '<td> &middot; <a href="http://'.$r['domain'].'">'.$r['domain'].'</a> </td>'."\r\n";
                if(++$i % 2 != 0) { echo '</tr>'."\r\n"; }
                }
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$s++` instead of `++$s`, so you test the value **before** you increment it. And there's no need to use a separate `$i` variable, you can just use the same `$s` variable without incrementing it.

```
$s = 0;
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($s++ % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<tr>\r\n";
    }
    echo '<td> &middot; <a href="http://'.$r['domain'].'">'.$r['domain'].'</a> </td>'."\r\n";
    if ($s % 2 == 0) {
        echo "</tr>\r\n";
    }
}
// If we ended loop without closing the row, do it now
if ($s % 2 == 0) {
    echo "</tr>\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to build a 2-column table? You don't need two counters for that, one will do:

```
$cells = 0;
while(...) {
   if (($cells % 2) == 0) {
      echo '<tr>';   // start a new row for cells 0, 2, 4, etc...
   }
   echo '<td> ....';
   if (($cells % 2) == 1) {
     echo '</tr>'; // close the row after outputting cells 1,3,5,etc...
   }
   $cells++;
}
```